# Gmail addon - how do I find the current draft ID

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api, gmail-addons

I'm building a gmail addon which lets users insert a template into the compose window.

It works fine but I'd like to get the ID of the draft they're editing and I can't figure out how.

It's not safe to assume it's the most recent draft as I'm not creating the draft programmatically.